# Disable "The last time you opened *, it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows" dialog in OSX 10.8

Tags: macos

I managed to successfully silence the CrashReport dialog, but when my application crashes and I restart it, I get the annoying dialog as from Title. Is there a way to prevent it to appear, and just let the application run without interruption?

Comment: Would fixing your application be an option? I mean, these dialogues are there shame you.

Comment: @JustSid: That is a good point if you code alone, not if you have to deploy a test machine that must constantly run the testsuite and gets stuck and needs a manual kick in the groin every time someone breaks the code.

Comment: Whoops, and here I was thinking you wanted to deploy broken software and don't have the customers notice it. I apologize.

Answer (score 22):

Try this to get rid of the reopening windows:

```
defaults write -app "Application Name" NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

You may also disable it for every application by selecting this option in the preferences: "Close windows when quitting an application"

And for others reading this thread, to remove the CrashReport do this:

```
defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType none
```

Also note that in the [source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80900/suppressing-reopen-windows-dialog-when-restarting-a-crashed-program-in-mountai) of this information they say:

> For this to work one needs to check the box, open the program in
>   question and immediately close it. On the next re-opening it will work
>   without Resume.

You may also have to delete:

```
/Users/…/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/org.python.python.savedState/
```

Comment: I am sorry, I've been busy all week and I forgot about this bounty. If it works, I'll reopen the bounty and give you the remaining 50.

Comment: How to get that app name? I'm getting this weird dialog for my python script. I tried `Python` as app name but got `Couldn't find an application named "Python"; defaults unchanged`.

Comment: **UPD**: `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/Python.app` worked fine as app name.

Comment: **UPD2** ... but has no effect, the dialog appeared again.

Comment: I updated a bit the answer, with a tip I read in the source of that information.

Comment: @Equidamoid Deleting the saved state worked for me.  (See edited answer.)

Comment: I'm finding this doesn't work on Big Sur.  I have no clue if it works on other OS versions.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem with google chrome and I could solve it by reading the following link:

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22716083?hl=en

Drew Z recommends the following solution there which worked for me:

> 1. In the Mac menu bar at the top of the screen, click Go.
> 2. Select Go to Folder.
> 3. Enter ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/ in the text field, then press Go.
> 4. Locate the folder called "Default" in the directory window that opens and rename it as "Backup default."
> 5. Try opening Google Chrome again. A new "Default" folder is automatically created as you start using the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Voila! I've just solved this problem by deleting all Unity-related files inside ~Library/Caches folder on my Mac!

Answer (score 1):

For those trying to accomplish this

`defaults write -app "Application Name" NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false`

with Python, you may get the error `Couldn't find an application named "Python"; defaults unchanged`.

To solve this, repeat the process to get the "reopen windows?" pop-up again, but do not choose an option in the pop-up – leave it alone for now. Right-click on the Python application's icon on the dock and choose "Show in Finder". Right-click on the application icon within Finder, hold the option key, and click `Copy "Python" as pathname"`. Paste that in as the "Application Name" for the command above and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this for a specific Xcode scheme by going to Edit Scheme, choosing the Options tab, and checking the box labeled "Launch application without state restoration."

[image]

However, this will *only* apply when you actually launch the application from Xcode; it won't disable the dialog when launching by double-clicking in Finder, or when launching from the terminal.

(As best I can tell, there no way for AppKit/NSApplication-based apps to do what UIKit apps can do with [UIApplicationDelegate's `application:shouldRestoreApplicationState:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622987-application?language=objc) and disable persistent state entirely for the application.)